# AWS Step Functions describe_execution

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-step-functions

I am running a state machine by invoking the execution using start_execution from boto3.client('stepfunctions') which executes it successfully.

Now i want to grab the Execution Output so i'm using describe_execution. but the problem is when it logs, i can't get the output as the status is still RUNNING. how can i make this describe_execution to wait until the status is SUCCEEDED

```
SF_CLIENT = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
sf_output = SF_CLIENT.start_execution(
                stateMachineArn=os.environ['STATE_MACHINE_ARN'], input=input)
            sf_response = SF_CLIENT.describe_execution(
                executionArn=sf_output['executionArn'])
            status = sf_response['status']

            while status != 'SUCCEEDED':
                sf_response = SF_CLIENT.describe_execution(
                    executionArn=sf_output['executionArn'])
                LOGGER.info("%s: %s" % ("EXECUTION STILL RUNNING", sf_response))
                if status != 'SUCCEEDED':
                    continue
                elif status == 'SUCCEEDED':
                    break

            LOGGER.info("%s: %s" % ("STEP FUNCTION EXECUTION OUTPUT", sf_output))
            LOGGER.info("%s: %s" % ("STEP FUNCTION EXECUTION RESPONSE", sf_response))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initial code was almost correct, but there are some mistakes.
This is a code which works:

```
sf_output = sf_client.start_execution(
    stateMachineArn=STATE_MACHINE_ARN,
    input= json.dumps(your_input)
)

while True:
    time.sleep(2) # don't need to check every nanosecond

    sf_response = sf_client.describe_execution(executionArn=sf_output['executionArn'])
    status = sf_response['status'] # BE SURE TO GET THE CURRENT STATE

    print("%s: %s" % ("> Status...", status))

    if status == 'RUNNING':
        continue
    elif status == 'FAILED':
        raise Exception("%s: %s" % ("! ERROR ! Execution FAILED: ", sf_response))
    else: # SUCCEEDED
        break
```

Of course, you can change the behavior of the FAILED state.

Comment: If you need more detailed Error Message one the failed status you can use this call:
```response_history = sf_client.get_execution_history(
                executionArn=sf_output['executionArn'],
                maxResults=1,
                reverseOrder=True,
                includeExecutionData=False
            )
            raise Exception('Failed to execute SFN: ' + response_history['events'][0]['executionFailedEventDetails']['cause'] + '. State is : ' + state)```

Answer (score 0):

As you figure it out StartExecution is async and doesn't wait for execution to finish.

Here are some options to consider:

- Use StartSyncExecution that returns the result and by nature is sync operation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.start_sync_execution
- add whatever you want to do after execution as steps to the end of your execution.
- trigger your next operation by sending SQs, Event bridge,... Events as a last step in your state machine.
- wait for execution to finish by checking Describe execution or Cloud watch events. But this solution should be your last resort. There are many shortcomings without. Describe Execution has rate limit and also some other limitations to consider.